# Does zero_as_missing parameter affects categorical features? LightGBM

Tags: lightgbm

Dealing with categorical features while training LightGBM model implies encoding them as integers and providing categorical_feature parameter with their indices or names.

LightGBM documentation says that:

> Tree decision rule works best when categorical features are presented
>   by consecutive integers starting from zero

and

> all negative values will be treated as missing values

My question is: when zero_as_missing parameter is set, does it refer only to continuous features, and categorical will still be considered missing if their value is negative?

> zero_as_missing ︎, default = false, type = bool
>
> ```
> set this to true to treat all zero as missing values (including the unshown values in LibSVM / sparse matrices)
> ```